# Snap store unable to uninstall application

Tags: apple, snap-store, electron

I am having problems with the apple-music-electron package:
[apple music electron error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NyFl.png)

so I decided to reinstall it. but when trying to do that snap store displays an error saying: 'Unable to remove "apple music electron" cannot perform the following tasks.'
and when trying to remove it from the terminal it also fails when trying to "save data in automatic snapshot".

[image]

Edit:
I installed the application with ubuntu software, basically snap store disguised, and I am on ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: please [edit] your question with details of your ubuntu version and the commands you used to install/remove the snap.

Comment: @24601 just did, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `--purge` parameter in terminal and the app was removed completely. I still don't know what caused the originial issue.
This is an example of the command:

`sudo snap remove --purge apple-music-electron`